# Password protect audio file for Whatsapp based service

Tags: encryption, password-protection, whatsapp

I'm creating a service which sends audio files via Whatsapp to it's users daily.

The thing is that i want to prevent people from sharing the audio files, so i thought of password protection of each audio file sent, with passwords composed by the user's sensitive information (example: social security number or equivalent, so that the user would be discoraged to pass along his own password to strangers online).

I've been looking for a  solution (without success so far) with 4 requirements in mind:

1) It needs to encrypt the file itself, not a folder that contains it

2) Audios must be easily sent and accessed via Whatsapp

3) Audios must be opened by customers without requiring the installation of apps. Just tap in the password and that's it.

4) It needs to work offline.

If there are other solutions to prevent or at least make file sharing more difficult without getting in the way of the user experience, please point out. Just keep in mind that it has to work in a Whatsapp broadcasting context, both in Android and IOS.

I know that everything online can and will be pirated, but i want to just make an effort to protect the product.

Comment: Do not use use a SSN, it is best to not ever have a user's SSN.

Comment: Yeah, i just gave the SSN as a reference. But anyway, do you have another suggestion, now when it comes to the way to do what i need to do, please? Thanks for the tip !